# Retrieving values from an array in Twig

Tags: php, arrays, twig

I'm trying to display the title of my categories, but something prevents and returns no results, the object is called 'filters'

My code

```
{% for categolian in filters.brands %}
    {% for item in categolian %}
        <li>
            <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.title }}</a>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

The Array

```
[categories] => Array
  (
  [title] => Categorias
  [applied] => 
  [items] => Array
  (
      [0] => Array
      (
      [title] => EPSON
      [count] => 2
      [url] => /mvc/store/catalog/?categoria=8
      [type] => link
      [applied] => 0
      )

      [1] => Array
      (
      [title] => HP
      [count] => 18
      [url] => /mvc/store/catalog/?categoria=10
      [type] => link
      [applied] => 0
      )

  )

  )
```

What I need...

```
<li>
   <a href="/mvc/store/catalog/?categoria=8"> EPSON </a>
</li>
<li>
   <a href="/mvc/store/catalog/?categoria=10"> HP </a>
</li>
```

but I do not have any results

Comment: It looks like you might need `for item in categolian.items`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the array you dumped represents `filters.brands` then

`{% for item in categolian.items %}`

would be correct

`categolian` is the array with keys `'title'`, `'applied'`, `'items'`...

`categolian.items` is yet another sub array.